# Webpack Muti Page Application bundle the image into different fold

Tags: javascript, webpack, urlloader

I have a  Multi Page Application,

```
entry: {
        vendor: ['vue', 'vue-router'],
        index: path.join(__dirname,'../src/pages/index' ,'main.js'),
        page2: path.join(__dirname,'../src/pages/page2' ,'main.js'),
    },
```

add the url-loader like this:

```
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                  limit: 10000,
                  name: '/img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
```

after `npm run build` i get a dist fold like this :
[dist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af5xh.jpg)

but I want bundle the img fold into the different fold like this:

```
        ├─index
        |   ├─img   //bundle img fold here
        |   ├─css
        |   └─js 
        |
        ├─page1
        |   ├─img      //bundle img fold here
        |   ├─css
        |   ├─js
        |   └─index.html
        |
        ├─page2
        |   ├─img    //bundle img fold here
        |   ├─css
        |   ├─js
        |   └─index.html
        |
```

is it possible do like this？

Comment: Multiple configuration can be a solution https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations

Comment: @MAshrafulA thanks for the reply! That's basically exactly what I wanted.